# Vue Local Data Using Getter

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to set a data property (in Classroom) based on what's in the store (of Lesson). But I keep getting `undefined`. How can I get that value and set it in data?

**Classroom.vue:**

```
data(){
  return {
    selectedOption: this.currentLesson
  }
}

computed: Object.assign({},
  mapGetters({
    currentLesson: "lesson/current"
  })
)
```

**lesson.js:**

```
const state = {
  current: {}
}

const getters = {
  current(){
    return state.current
  },
}
```

**index.js:**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    lesson,
    user
  }
})
```

Comment: looks like `lesson.js` is a vuex store. Could you provide the store module registration code?

Comment: In my index.js, I just export lesson and user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:

The component's `data` function is called before the computed values are set up. So you cannot use computed properties inside `data` function. (That is reasonable, because some computed getters might rely on certain properties from data. It might cause infinite loops if we set up computed values before calling `data`).

In your case, if you want `selectedOption` to always be the same as `currentLesson`, then you don't need to put it in the component's local data, just use `this.currentLesson` directly in your view template.

However, if you just want to set up an initial value for `selectedOption` based on `lesson/current`, you can explicitly access it via:

```
selectedOption: this.$store.getters['lesson/current']
```

Or by using a lifecycle hook like `created` or `mounted`:

```
created () {
    this.selectedOption = this.$store.getters['lesson/current']
    // or `this.selectedOption = this.currentLesson` if you keep that mapped getter
}
```

Original answer:

`currentLesson: "lesson/current"` is the "namespaced getter" syntax. You need to set `namespaced: true` for your lesson store definition. Did you set that field when you export `lesson.js`?

Comment: Yes, I did set `namespaced: true` when exporting lesson.js. I can use `currentLesson` as a computed property but I couldn't use it under `data`.

Comment: @jj008 I've updated the answer. See if that addresses your problem.